# APC Smart-UPS turning off by itself?

Tags: ups, apc, apc-smart-ups

I have an APC Smart-UPS 3000.

Last Sunday, it turned off by itself. Noone was in the office and noone was logged in at the time it happened.

What could cause this ? I'm concerned it may happen again.

The log show the outputs "has been commanded to shutdown", but does not explain by who or where. Local panel ? Scheduled test ? Remote ? What are the possibilities ?

UPS web interface is password protected. Please see the log here :
Most recent event is the sysadmin logging in to check what's up...

```
08/11/2019  19:39:25    apc Web user 'apc' logged in from 10.22.0.14.   0x0015
08/11/2019  12:19:56    Device  UPS: The power for switched outlet group 3, Outlet Group 3, is now turned on.   0x0134
08/11/2019  12:19:56    Device  UPS: The power for switched outlet group 2, Outlet Group 2, is now turned on.   0x0134
08/11/2019  12:19:56    Device  UPS: The power for switched outlet group 1, Outlet Group 1, is now turned on.   0x0134
08/11/2019  12:19:56    Device  UPS: The output power is now turned on. 0x0113
08/11/2019  12:19:55    Device  UPS: The output power is turned off.    0x0114
08/11/2019  12:19:55    Device  UPS: The graceful shutdown period has ended.    0x014F
08/11/2019  12:19:55    Device  UPS: Switched outlet group 3, Outlet Group 3, has been commanded to shutdown with on delay. 0x0174
08/11/2019  12:19:55    Device  UPS: The power for switched outlet group 3, Outlet Group 3, is now turned off.  0x0135
08/11/2019  12:19:55    Device  UPS: Switched outlet group 2, Outlet Group 2, has been commanded to shutdown with on delay. 0x0174
08/11/2019  12:19:55    Device  UPS: The power for switched outlet group 2, Outlet Group 2, is now turned off.  0x0135
08/11/2019  12:19:55    Device  UPS: Switched outlet group 1, Outlet Group 1, has been commanded to shutdown with on delay. 0x0174
08/11/2019  12:19:55    Device  UPS: The power for switched outlet group 1, Outlet Group 1, is now turned off.  0x0135
07/12/2019  22:22:43    Device  UPS: The battery is now installed.  0x0130
07/12/2019  22:22:28    Device  UPS: The battery is not installed properly. 0x012F
```

Running latest firmware :

```
Network Management Card AOS v6.6.4
Smart-UPS & Matrix-UPS APP v6.6.4
NMC Serial Number: (hidden)

Model: Smart-UPS X 3000
UPS Serial Number: (hidden)
Firmware Revision: UPS 02.0 (ID10)
```

If anyone has any idea it'd be much appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Oct 21 2019, additional info : a few days ago, the UPS went OFFLINE and can no longer be started due to an "inverter fault". So it is possible this type of unexpected shutdown is a sign of a fault within the UPS and I urge anyone running into the same type of trouble to be careful with the unit. I wish APC was providing more detailed diagnostics when it happens.

Comment: It seems that I have a similar issue but I do not have the network card. See https://serverfault.com/questions/988746/apc-smart-ups-3000-turning-off-but-passing-own-test -- maybe you got an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, same as mine Smart-UPS SRT 3000 (+3 additional battery packs) switched out outlet group 1 and 2 when battery capacity was 70% without obvious reason.

```
09.10.2019 23:51:59 Device UPS: The power for switched outlet group 2, Outlet Group 2, is now turned off.   0x0135
09.10.2019 23:51:59 Device UPS: The power for switched outlet group 1, Outlet Group 1, is now turned off.   0x0135
09.10.2019 23:51:59 Device UPS: A DC bus overvoltage exists.    0x0163
09.10.2019 23:51:58 Device UPS: The output power is turned off. 0x0114
09.10.2019 23:51:58 Device UPS: The graceful shutdown period has ended. 0x014F
09.10.2019 23:51:58 Device UPS: No longer on battery power. 0x010A
09.10.2019 23:51:57 Device UPS: An input voltage or frequency problem no longer prevents switching to bypass mode.  0x0210
09.10.2019 23:15:28 Device UPS: Bypass not in range ; distorted waveform.   0x020F
09.10.2019 23:15:28 Device UPS: On battery power in response to rapid change of input.  0x0109
```

Test results from UPS:

```
Test        Result  Date        Source          Cause
Self-Test   Passed  14.10.2019  management device   NA
Calibration Passed  04.10.2019  management device   NA

State of Charge
99.0 %
Runtime Remaining
2hr 14min 27sec
Battery Voltage
106.9  VDC
Replacement Battery Cartridge SKU
xxx
Battery Pack Status
Battery Pack        Health      Status
Internal Pack       [Okay]  OK  [Okay]  OK
Battery Pack 1      [Okay]  OK  [Okay]  OK
Battery Pack 2      [Okay]  OK  [Okay]  OK
Battery Pack 3      [Okay]  OK  [Okay]  OK
```

[Network Management Card (NMC) Reports Graceful Shutdown](https://www.schneider-electric.com/en/faqs/FA157525/)

> Another example is when a UPS has a fault condition and goes into failure bypass (where bypass is available). Most Smart-UPS on-line designs, such as SURT and SURTA models, turn off the UPS's battery charger when in failure bypass. As a result, the battery will discharge over time. When the battery hits a low battery condition, the UPS wants to shutdown the UPS's loads as it cannot maintain failure bypass forever (a minimum battery voltage is required to keep the logic power supply on for the on-line Smart-UPS).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My UPS suddenly went OFFLINE a few days after my post, due to an "inverter fault". I suggest you take steps to protect your equipment and services if the UPS is powering anything critical or without redundancy as this type of behavior might be a sign of impending failure...

Answer (score 0):

Is any any software monitoring the UPS?  Was there a power outage?

It would appears you have a three phase supply to the UPS.  If any phase goes offline, I would expect it to begin the power down cycle.  It is common for the UPS to do a power off following notifying systems to shutdown.  This is required to bring the systems back up following the shutdown request.

I have used the NUT (Network UPS Tool) software to manage the UPS and systems.  Its documentation explains the shutdown/restart cycle.  Most other software behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a battery problem and when the UPS tries to make it's periodical self-test it cannot sustain the power from the battery.

You should access its interface and perform an intentional battery test to see if it succeeds or not.