# APC Smart-UPS 3000 turning off but passing own test

Tags: ups, battery, apc

I have APC Smart-UPS 3000 at home which I got hand and apparently when the power goes down it just shuts down instead of switching to backup.

Based on how it behaves I have reasons to believe is not the batteries. Apparently there is no service nearby and I am sure shipping it would too expensive.

Sadly it does not have a network card on it so the only way to debug its condition is via the front panel.

I recorded a video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIVx7s68rzs to exemplify better how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

The mainboard might be faulty.

Your only hope is a cold reset and watch after if it work better after.

> The Cold start procedure is used to determine if a UPS is functional
>   if it will not turn on when plugged into utility power. The Brain Dead
>   procedure performs a hard reset of the Smart-Ups microprocessor. It
>   does not however reset saved preferences.
>
> Resolution:
>
> Cold Start: This is a great way to establish if a UPS will not turn on
>   due to bad input power. Never use a Cold Start to troubleshoot a bad
>   battery LED as it will clear the light most every time even if the
>   battery is actually bad. This is because the self-test is comparing
>   the battery health compared to the load attached. If there is no load
>   attached, the battery will appear healthy.   1) Turn off and unplug
>   the Smart-UPS from wall. Remove any attached load. 2) Press and hold
>   the power button (labeled ""I/TEST"" on legacy non-LCD screen units)
>   on the front of the UPS until you hear a LONG beep. 3) Let go DURING
>   the long beep. If you let go after the beep ends you will need to try
>   again. 4) UPS should go through its' normal self test and end up on
>   battery with 4 beeps every 30 seconds. This shows that the UPS is
>   functioning correctly and can both pass a self test and function on
>   battery. 5) You can now plug your UPS back into the wall. If the input
>   power is acceptable the UPS will transfer back online.

Comment: Aparently cold-boot test end-up with "internal fault" and the middle (3/5) battery led on as on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChBs_yHg5AY :(

Answer (score 1):

You pinged me on my similar post here :
[APC Smart-UPS turning off by itself?](https://serverfault.com/questions/979158/apc-smart-ups-turning-off-by-itself)

Just wanted to let you know that a few days after I posted, the UPS suddenly went OFFLINE with no prior warning due to an "inverter fault" and will not turn back on. It's basically broken now.

So I would consider any suspicious behavior with this type of UPS as a sign of impending failure. Take action now if your UPS is serving anything without redundancy, that's my advice.

Hope this helps